# Alerting objects via constructor function error

Tags: javascript, function, object

I usually can find my own errors in ten minutes but I can't seem to pinpoint what I'm doing wrong here. Can someone please tell me why I cannot get an alert for either of these functions?

```
var Emp = function( vEname, vSal ) {

  this.Ename = vEname;
  this.Sal = vSal;

  this.getAnnSal: function() {
    return this.Sal * 12;
  }

  this.getQuarterSal: function() {
    return this.Sal * 3;
  }

};

var oEmp = new Emp("Jag", 2300);

alert("Annual salary: " + oEmp.getAnnSal());
alert("Quarter Salary: " + oEmp.getQuarterSal());
```

Comment: There is a syntax error, have you checked the js console?

Comment: Nope, no errors. listed -__- . I'm running this on I.E.

Comment: Then you aren't looking in the console, or you have something consuming errors

Comment: It says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : testseries15.html:14"

Comment: @Shinji-san so "Uncaught SyntaxError" equals to "no errors. listed"?

Comment: No I just found that.

Comment: I'm wondering how you manage to find your own errors in ten minutes if you do not know how to view syntax errors in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.getAnnSal: function()
```

should be

```
this.getAnnSal = function() { ... }
```

however, that will add the function to every instance of the object.

If you are going to have more than one instance, you should use prototypes - like so:

```
var Emp = function (vEname, vSal) {
  this.Ename = vEname;
  this.Sal = vSal;
}

Emp.prototype.getAnnSal = function() {
  return this.Sal * 12;
}
```

In that way, the function is available for all instances of Emp, but not duplicated.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for the advice.